# Can a $z$ score be in the hundreds?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> The lifetime of light bulbs are distributed normally with mean $5$
> months and standard deviation $1.6$ months. Find the probability that
> $10$ light bulbs will last $5$ years if they will be replaced as soon
> as they are faulty.

If I let $L$ be the lifetime of a light bulb, then I have $L\sim N\left(5,1.6^2\right)$.

The sum of $10$ gives $\frac{S}{10}\sim N\left(5,\:\left(\frac{1.6}{\sqrt{10}}\right)^2\right)$,

which I can use to evaluate whats required: $P(\frac{S}{10}≥60)$ , where I converted to months to match the units.

Then I proceed to get an incorrect $z$ score value:

$$1-P\left(z<\frac{60-5}{\frac{1.6}{\sqrt{10}}}\right)=1-P\left(z<108.70\right)$$

which is ridiculous. What went wrong?

Comment: You want $P(S \ge 60) = P(S/10 \ge 6)$, not $P(S/10 \ge 60)$.

Comment: Ok, that would fix the mistake then. Can you explain what is logically meant by $P(S \ge 60) = P(S/10 \ge 6)$? Why are we equating them?

Comment: @user71207 : Because, transparently, $S \geq 60$ if and only if $S/10 \geq 6$.

Comment: ohhhhh I see my mistake. It is the power of *all* the light bulbs to last $60$ months, not the average. I knew something was off.

Answer (score 1):

As @Angrayavian comments, you are mixing months and years.

$L \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 10(5) = 50, \sigma=\sqrt{10(1.6)} = 4)$
You seek $P(L > 60) = 1 - P(L \le 60) = 0.0062.$ Computed in R:

```
1 - pnorm(60, 50, 4)
[1] 0.006209665
```

Standardizing:

$$P(L \le 60) = P\left(Z=\frac{L-\mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{60-50}{4} = 2.5\right) = 0.9938,$$
rounded to about four places as in normal tables; $1 - .9938 = 0.0062.$

```
pnorm(2.5) 
[1] 0.9937903
1 - pnorm(2.5) 
[1] 0.006209665

curve(dnorm(x, 50, 4), 35, 65, lwd=2, col="blue", ylab="PDF",
      main="Density of NORM(50,4)")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=60, col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]